Gridsearch CV using more cpus than requested
Hi I cannot figure out why Gridsearch is using more cpu than requested. It stays within the requested resources when GridSearchCV(.., n_job=1) but this takes ages to run. What I understand is that OMP_NUM_THREADS limit the CPU each job uses and n_job is the number of jobs to run in parallel. Could you point out what the problem is please?
In the PBS job file:

#PBS -l select=2:ncpus=60:mem=50GB


export OMP_NUM_THREADS=60
python gridsearch.py



In gridsearch.py file
GridSearchCV(..., n_jobs = 2, pre_dispatch='n_jobs')


But this is using >200% of the CPU requested and I have to kill the job. Could someone please help?
Thanks

How do you identify that >200% of the requested resources are used? As I understand the n_jobs, they don't spawn new processes, but just spawn more threads. Therefore select=2 has no impact and you will still only use 1 pbs slot. The omp_num_threads setting does not limit the total number of threads to be spawned by the process but only how many threads are spawned from each initial thread (created with the n_jobs setting). With your settings, I would expect 121 total threads to be created. Setting omp_num_threads=29 and n_jobs=2 you should stay below the requested 60 threads.

To limit the total number of threads used by openmp, you could set omp_thread_limit=60. For your program this might result in a very bad load balance. The first grid search job might eat up all 60 openmp threads, so that the second job will run with just one openmp thread.
